# How do I remove CodeIntel in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using ST3 build 3114. How do I stop the code completion popup? I can't find SublimeCodeIntel anywhere in my Package Control to remove, I added SublimeCodeIntel to my 'ignored_packages' in settings which did nothing, and I searched my entire hard drive for *CodeIntel* and found nothing. Why does this keep popping up? I would actually like to just disable it for CSS files, but that doesn't work too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked for CSS autocompletions, but the box is still coming up with other stuff.  I guess I'll wait for the code change.

Answer (score 0):

The autocompletion of property names in CSS is supplied by the built in `CSS` package. To disable it:

1. Install [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control, if it is not already installed.
2. Open the Command Palette
3. Type `PRV: O` and select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
4. Select `CSS`
5. Select `css_completions.py`
6. Delete the contents of the file
7. Save it

To disable other auto completion sources (like word/buffer completion) in CSS files, you can add the following to your user preferences:

```
"auto_complete_selector": "meta.tag - punctuation.definition.tag.begin, source - comment - string.quoted.double.block - string.quoted.single.block - string.unquoted.heredoc - source.css",
```

Note that this is the default `auto_complete_selector` value with `- source.css` added to the end of it.

Comment: We need to add an option to disable this when `"auto_complete": false` is present and when `-source.css` is included in `"auto_complete_selector"`.

Comment: Should be pretty simple: put `# If auto_complete is false, don't trigger` on line 434, then 435-436 should be `if not self.view.settings().get("auto_complete"):` and `return []`, respectively.

Comment: @MattDMo I have been thinking about this some more, and believe that checking the `auto_complete` preference from `on_query_completions` is not a good idea, because it would disable it even when the user explicitly presses the autocomplete key combination etc.

Comment: I thought Ctrl-Space didn't work if autocomplete was off?

Comment: @MattDMo no, it can still be triggered manually (I just checked). The description for the `auto_complete` preference is: `Enable auto complete to be triggered automatically when typing.`